# unable to start service intent : not found

Tags: android

I used AlarmManager to call up an activity every interval, however, the interval must can be changed. The activity is just a another function that I have changed into pendingIntent. 
The calling class is shown  below, which is also the main class. The called class is shown after the calling class. At the end , is the manifest file, which might contain the source of error.

```
  Timer_test:

  package com.timer_test;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.app.AlarmManager;
  import android.app.PendingIntent;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.os.SystemClock;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;

 public class Timer_testActivity extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */

   private PendingIntent mAlarmSender;
   int update_freq = 1;
   Intent toast_make;
   int interval;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button button5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    Button button10 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button10);

    toast_make = new Intent("com.timer_test.toast_testClass");
    mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(Timer_testActivity.this, 0, toast_make           ,0);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0){
            update_freq = 1;
            timer_schedule();
    }
    });

    button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0){
            update_freq = 3;
            timer_schedule();
    }
    });

    button5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0){
            update_freq = 5;
            timer_schedule();
    }
    });

    button10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0){
            update_freq = 10;
            timer_schedule();
    }
    });
}

  public void timer_schedule(){

    long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

    interval = update_freq*1000;
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstTime, interval,    mAlarmSender);

}

 package com.timer_test;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class toast_test extends Activity{

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    onClick("yes");
}

public void onClick(String n) {
    Toast.makeText(toast_test.this,n,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

     }


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.timer_test"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Timer_testActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.timer_test.toast_test"/>

  </application>
 </manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

`toast_test`  is activity and in manifest you declared it as service

Comment: true..However, I followed an example that use toast_test as an pendingIntent, and start it with getSystemService of the AlarmManager.. can I start any activity as an intent and use AlarmManager?

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking but Intents are like message passed between activities. You can start activity by sending intent. You just need to write intent filter inside your manifest file respective to your activity.